# Gamification skill tree

Tags: php, mysql, json, tree

I'm working on creating a skill tree for my own web site. I'm having problem on how to create one. I have what I call a base class for skills. My idea was to add a tier or level of the skill, and add a skill required to be mastered before it is unlockable. What I want is a borderlands like skill tree. Any ideas on how to code a skill tree? The data could be stored in a mysql database or json file. I've only implemented the skillnode class, which doesn't have any methods just attributes. Each skill belongs to a speciality. Each skill modifies a stat which can be created by the user.

```
   // skill for a class, builds skill tree
   class Skill
   {
    const $maxLevels = 5; // sets max levels as an unchangeable value
    private $name; // name of the skill
    private $speciality; // class the skill belongs to
    private $modifiesStat; // stat skill modifies
    private $increase; // array for each tier for the increase in percents needs bound checks against levels
    private $type; // effect type, i.e increase or decrease
    private $icon; // url or path to skill icon
    private $image; // url or path to skill logo
    private $locked; // if skill is unlocked or not
    private $mastered; // if all tiers are unlocked true or false
    private $disabled; // if the skill is active and can be used true or fall
    private $requires; // skill this skill requires to unlock (parent skill for)
    private $conditionalStat; // stat modified stat requires a check on
    private $condition; // method used for check on depended stat, requires condition class
    private $conditions; // list of valid conditions for sanity check on condition
    private $skillType; // type of skill
    private $levels; // number of unlock levels
    private $invested; // number of skills invested in the skill
   }
```

Comment: I would suggest to follow some product with gamifications implementation then add the similar features in your site, 
http://blogs.clicksoftware.com/clickipedia/top-25-best-examples-of-gamification-in-business/
normally gamification has many things(PBLs), you have to mange that too with points 
http://www.sitepoint.com/building-engaging-web-apps-game-mechanics/

Comment: I thought about just pulling the data from mysql or a json file and creating a tree and performing the display stuff with javascript using the  array or json data. I figure it would save memory that way instead of using a class for every skill